# When can I use "sum", "amount" and "total"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, word-difference, synonyms

I think they can be synonymous in some context, but how to learn in which context I can use one and not another? Can you explain and give example about the precise meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> amount

is only a number expressing a quantity

> sum

is the result of **adding** numbers together

> total

is the result of  calculation, not necessarily by addition

> **Sum** and **total** are **amounts**.
>   A **sum** is a **total** amount through *addition*.
>   A **total** is a cumulative amount.
>
> **2 + 4 + 5**, sum is **11**, total is **11**, amount is **11**
>   **2 *4 *5**, total is **40**, amount is **40**, there is no sum since it is multiplication

Answer (score 3):

***Sum***:

The most common meaning for the word sum is the result of the addition of two or more numbers/items.

- *The sum of 1 and -22 is -21*

Or the action of doing the addition.

- *Can you sum these two numbers for me?*

The other meaning is a particular amount of money.

- *They can't afford this sum.* (In this example we can also use the word amount: *They can't afford this amount.*)

***Amount:***

Noun: It means *a quantity of something*

- *The amount of oxygen in air.*

And is usually used when talking about money

- He bets a huge amount on the lottery.

Verb: to come out to be/to total

- *She won't amount to anything in her life.*
- *The loss amounts/sums/totals to three billion.*

***Total:***

Noun: complete/overall

- *His party was a total failure.*
- *She won a total of three competitions.*

Verb: As a verb, **total** and **amount** are **synonyms**.

I hope this was helpful!